# Character Rig Texture Skewing/Streching

Tags: texturing, uv, rigging

TL;DR - Rig causes texture to stretch in places ( like on the joints; hips, butt, shoulders etc).

Having a hard time finding alternative methods or tricks to fix my problem ( search for hours/days ). I all ready know to use multiple UV maps or materials. I have to use low res and low-med poly and i could re-weight but it just moves the problem to a different location.

Normally you'd just use multiple textures and UV maps but i only want to use 1 UV Map, 1 Texture and a single rig. I want to save time by only using a single of each and id compromise on it with minimizing stretching and i don't think its possible to out right stop it with that kind of restriction, especially cause its low-med poly and low res texture.

I want to use this model for a video game and it would be an interesting challenge to get it to work better ( not perfectly ) with only a single texture, rig and UV map. Though i'm starting to doubt the validity of the challenge.

Thanks!

Note - I can post screen shots but only specific parts due to "offensive" content ( nudity ).

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer I'm at least half-way satisfied with but might not count towards the challenge. Additional loop cuts and smoothing out the weights helps by about 50-60% deformation of texture detail where as before it was like 80-90%.

EDIT: The loop cuts are redundant for the sake of the model's design and only exist to reduce texture skewing.

I'm also gonna use ( for specific parts only ) planes with full weight on single bones and just keep them away from the joints. I might also try half weights if it's centered perfectly in-between joints.

This does increase the poly/detail count significantly. I will still be looking out for new methods and trying different things.